# "Теории заговора" или "теории заговоров"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, единственное-множественное-число

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно: "теории заговор**а**" или "теории заговор**ов**"? Иными словами, как будет "теория заговора" во множественном числе?

Comment: Можете привести пример контекста?

Comment: @enkryptor ниже Вы совершенно правильно переформулировали этот мой вопрос: "Как поставить "теория заговора" во множественное число?" Именно это я и имел в виду. Вы полагаете, что тут есть зависимость от контекста? Ниже я уже приводил кое-какие примеры. Могу ещё такой привести: "Стариков и Фёдоров - известные мастера придумывать разнообразные теории заговора (-ов)".

Answer (score 2):

Трудно сказать без контекста.
Есть понятие "теория заговора". Множественного числа оно не имеет, поскольку эта теория известна в единичном экземпляре.
Следовательно, если здесь множественное число употреблено не по ошибке, то автор не расстривает нечто, так им названное, в непосредственной связи с известным термином. А коли так, оба варианта могут иметь право на существование - в зависимости от смысла и контекста вообще.

//======================

Меня, похоже, не до конца поняли. 
**Я говорю прежде всего о единственном числе в слове "теория"**. Вот оно-то безусловно единственное, поскольку это, как следует из определения, некоторое ученье (чтоб не заморачиваться выбором термина), объясняющие все серьезные исторические перемены заговорами и прочей конспирологией. 
Это нораьтное использование и оно требует единственного числа в слове **"заговор"**. Сами заговоры могут быть разные, но смысл в том, что сам заговор единственный для конкретного случая. Это не перевод, эта логика языка. Как "теория большого взрыва".

Вот про такое использование можно вести речь с точки зрения правильности.
Как только автор начинает говорить о каких-то **теориях** (во множественном), все разговоры о правильности с точки зрения терминологии перестают работать, это уже не термин - и только сам автор знает, что от имел в виду, **один заговор или несколько**.

Comment: В данном случае (в вопросе) под теорией заговора понимается конспирологическая теория, а точнее, конспирологическая версия, объясняющая что-либо. Примеры из той же статьи в Википедии: "Предпосылки возникновения теорий заговоров", "Существует множество теорий заговора относительно событий 11 сентября 2001 года". Или (мой пример): "Не будем, товарищи, плодить здесь никаких теорий заговора (-ов)" (указаны оба варианта, поскольку я не знаю, как правильно). На мой взгляд, здесь возможны только два варианта контекста: 1) теории заговора (-ов) вообще; 2) теории заговора (-ов) по конкретному поводу.

Comment: @adp тогда я не вижу возможности употреблять во множественном числе. Что там в Вики понаписали - это у них надо спросить.

Comment: @behemothus "на этот счёт есть две теории - что правительство захвачено инопланетянами и что всё купили евреи. Иногда эти теории объединяются в одну.."

Answer (score 1):

Случившийся пословный перевод с английского (conspiracy theory) привёл к *единственному* числу ("теория заговора"), хотя conspiracy здесь может трактоваться и нейтрально отн. множественности. Хотя термин в русском давно устоялся, по смыслу *theory* здесь не "теория", а "**версия**" заговора; словоупотребление, когда theory переводится с английского как "версия", характерно и для детективов. "Теория заговора" указывает одну из версий значимого события, причины которого не ясны, примеряя к нему некий **заговор** как вероятную причину. Расхождение между русскими понятиями "версия" и "теория" приводит к тому, что в публицистике понятие "теории заговора" употребляется с ироническим оттенком (некто помешался на странной теории). Собственно же "теорию", связанную с обширными квазинаучными исследованиями в данном направлении, называют "конспирологией" - в её рамках вполне уместны рассуждения о *множественных* заговорах.

Comment: Вопрос-то был не в том, сколько там заговоров, а в том, как поставить "теорию заговора" во множественное число.

Comment: Для меня вопрос больше похож на цитату (и её вариант), где слово "теория" в родитетельном падеже ед. числа.

Comment: Попросим автора уточнить.

Comment: @Alex_ander я не пойму, откуда у нас-то пошло английский термин conspiracy theory трактовать как некую единую, универсальную, всеобъемлющую теорию заговора (или как синоним термина "конспирология")? В английском conspiracy theory - это просто версия какого-либо события, основанная на том, что кто-то где-то тайно сговорился организовать это событие с какими-то своими целями. А русский буквальный перевод этого английского термина - "теория заговора" - означает что-то типа теории о том, что всё на свете есть чей-то заговор.

Comment: @adp Возможно, началось с журналистов-международников, которым поверхностно переведённое словосочетание показалось удобным в политической полемике: можно кого-то привязать к сомнительной "теории". Некоторые журналисты не слишком глубоко вникают в иноязычный текст и много чего говорят и пишут по незнанию. Напр. на Олимпиаде многие из них уверенно произносили китайские имена по английским правилам чтения, а могли бы за полчаса раз и навсегда разобраться - даже по википедии.

Answer (score 0):

Если отвечать на перефразированную (уточнённую) версию вопроса, то родительный падеж множественного числа -- это именно "заговоров", фиксируется любым словарём. См. например, тут: http://opencorpora.org/dict.php?act=edit&id=100694

По вопросу какое число употребить очень точно ответил @behemothus -- в русском языке принято использовать в ед. ч.

Answer (score 0):

Почитав ответы и поразмыслив сам, решил дать ответ на собственный вопрос. В данном случае *теория заговора* означает просто *версия заговора*. Поэтому вопрос о выборе между *теории заговор**а*** и *теории заговор**ов*** сводится к вопросу о выборе между *версии заговор**а*** и *версии заговор**ов***. Ясно, что решение этого последнего вопроса зависит от того, об одном или не об одном заговоре идёт речь в контексте. Если об одном - выбираем *заговор**а***, если не об одном - выбираем *заговор**ов***.

Например, если мы говорим о разных теориях заговора (-ов) относительно событий 11 сентября 2001 г., то ясно, что речь идёт о разных версиях **одного заговора** - заговора, стоящего за событиями 11 сентября 2001 г. Поэтому выбираем *заговор**а***: "Существует множество *теорий заговор**а*** относительно событий 11 сентября 2001 г."

А если мы говорим, например, о том, что Стариков и Фёдоров любят придумывать разнообразные теории заговора (-ов), то понятно, что речь идёт не об одном заговоре, а о **многих заговорах**: кто "на самом деле" стоял за Горбачёвым, кто "на самом деле" стоял за "Брексит", кто "на самом деле" управляет Америкой и пр. Поэтому выбираем *заговор**ов***: "Стариков и Фёдоров - известные мастера придумывать разнообразные *теории заговор**ов***".